# VS2012 crashes whenever intellisense starts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm a bit lost on this, but whenever I start typing in visual studio right before intellisense usually kicks in, the app crashes. It doesn't matter what project I'm working on. I've tried reinstalling and updating. I had other versions of VS installed, but removed all those. I've been using VS2012 for awhile and this problem just popped up yesterday.

[image]

Here is the stack trace:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid&
>   pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr
>   pvaOut)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid&
>   pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr
>   pvaOut)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid&
>   pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr
>   pvaOut)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(Guid&
>   pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr
>   pvaOut)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid&
>   pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr
>   pvaOut)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.Exec(Guid&
>   pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr
>   pvaOut)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.SendCommand(Guid
>   cmdGroup, UInt32 cmdID, Object inParam)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.TextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs
>   args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.b__0(KeyProcessor
>   p, TextCompositionEventArgs args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1e`1.<Dispatch>b__1a()
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object
>   errorSource, Action call)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.Dispatch[T](Action`2
>   action, T args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass18.b__17(Object
>   sender, TextCompositionEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>          at System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.UnsafeCompleteComposition(TextComposition
>   composition)
>          at System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.PostProcessInput(Object
>   sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler
>   postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>          at System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.UnsafeStartComposition(TextComposition
>   composition)
>          at System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.PostProcessInput(Object
>   sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler
>   postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessTextInputAction(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg,
>   Boolean& handled)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(MSG&
>   msg, Boolean& handled)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.ThreadMessageEventHandler.Invoke(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG&
>   msg)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG&
>   msg)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.PreTranslateInput(MSG[]
>   lpmsg, Boolean handled)   InnerException:

Comment: I have the same problem; nothing seems to make it go away